# Using grep inside a script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to search a file to find a word using grep. I'm trying to use it inside of a script but I am unable to get it to work. I'm a beginner at this so my code is probably not good. Here's what I have so far

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "apple", "book", "cat" >> file.txt

read -r filename
filename='file.txt'
"$4"=filename
"$1"=grep
"$2"=-R
```

So ideally I want the user to be able to type the name of the script on the command line along with the word they are searching for, which in this case would be "book".

```
user:~/dir$ ./wordfind.sh book
```

I may be doing this completely wrong, but when I run the above in the command line, it freezes and I have to Ctrl-Z to get out of it. Thanks.

Comment: if you check against a regexp where is this regexp?

Comment: if you're going to hardcode `filename='file.txt'` then why ask the user for a filename (`read -r filename`)? btw, the script is likely 'hanging' because it's waiting for you to enter a filename (ie, `read -r filename` tells the script to wait for the user to input something and hit <enter>); also not sure what you're trying to accomplish with the `"${4|1|2}"=....` constructs, nor how any of that's supposed to run a `grep` command; perhaps you want something as simple as `grep "${1:-undefined}" "${filename}"`?

Comment: Hi and welcome! What is the expected output?

Comment: @Madman I'm trying to get it to find the word "rice" in the file.txt. The $1, $2, etc are in the script so you don't have to type out the entire command on the command line. Instead of typing ./wordfind.sh grep -R rice file.txt  , I want to just be able to type ./wordfind rice , and it finds the word rice. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Also (re-)using positional variables in assignments is a bad idea; in your case `"$1"=grep` will overwrite whatever the user passed in on the command line.

Comment: @Andrew Please [edit] your question and add requested information or clarification there instead of answering in comments. Show the expected output for your example use case `./wordfind rice`. The quoting in your lines `echo "apple", "book", "cat" >> file.txt` etc. is strange. Using `echo "apple, book, cat" >> file.txt` or `echo apple, book, cat >> file.txt` you would get the same result, which is a line `apple, book, cat`. When run the script repeatedly without deleting `file.txt` you will append the same lines to the file again. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not clear enough.

This answer assumes that you want to call your script with a string or regex as the first argument, i.e. the search term must be quoted if it contains spaces or special characters.

You could change the script `wordfind.sh` to

```
#!/bin/bash

# note: I changed >> to > here to avoid duplicating the data on repeated calls
echo "apple", "book", "cat" > file.txt
echo "dad", "food", "girl" >> file.txt
echo "god", "hey", "linux" >> file.txt
echo "out", "owl", "rice" >> file.txt
echo "say", "toy", "zebra" >> file.txt

# Check if exactly one argument was specified.
if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
   echo "usage: $0 'regex'"
   exit 1
fi

grep "$1" file.txt
```

Examples:

```
$ ./wordfind.sh rice
out, owl, rice

$ ./wordfind.sh 'z.*a'
say, toy, zebra

$ ./wordfind.sh 'd, f'
dad, food, girl
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you for this! I'm sorry that my explanation wasn't very good, I'm still very new and trying to learn! I appreciate your patience and help!

Comment: @Andrew No need to apologize. Please improve your question as suggested.